# Creating multiple TextBoxes in the view from an string array in Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an array of string which I want to show a separate Textbox for each one of them in the View.

I tried to use it like this (which Items is of type `string[]`):

```
@foreach(var x in Model.Items) {<input asp-for="x" />}
```

But this does not work. I can of course go the old way:

```
 @foreach(var x in Model.Items) {<input name="items" value="x" />}
```

but I want to know how to do it MVC way.

Comment: Use a `for` loop and `asp-for="Model[i]"` (could also use `asp-for=@x"` since its `string[]`)

Comment: Use enumerables to store in modelview. You could Also use displayfor method am mvc iterate automaticaly and print like a foreach. http://blog.rodhowarth.com/2011/03/aspnet-mvccustom-displayfor-partial.html?m=1

Comment: @StephenMuecke this worked very great for me. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MVC, I would highly recommend putting the string array inside a viewmodel:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
   public string[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

And then point the model to SomeViewModel.  And, in the UI, do:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Items.Length; i++) {
   <input name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.Items[i])" value="@Model.Items[i]" />
}
```

or use `Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items[i])` as an alternative to client-side input.